# Filter in setup playbook

Tags: bash, ansible

I try get ansible facts and don't understand how correctly write filter. I need get 2 facts - ansible_lsb and ansible_hostname. Example:

```
ansible 192.168.250.* -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_(hostname|lsb)'
```

but it not work. Need help, how to show some facts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`filter` pattern in `setup` module is a simple "filename" pattern.
It uses [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) under the hood (see [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts.py#L3737)).

So you can only use simple filters like `filter=ansible_user*` out of the box.

If you want to make some custom filtering, see my other answer about filtering facts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182680/2795592).