# Global config for Ansible modules

Tags: proxy, ansible

I'm using an Ansible role from Ansible Galaxy which downloads some software from the Internet and then installs it. It uses the `get_url` module to do that.
The problem is that I am working behind a corporate proxy that will first download the software and then send it to the Ansible playbook running. It causes `get_url` to hit its default timeout of 10s. It is working fine if I increase the timeout.
As I'm using a third party role, I don't want to modify it and was wondering if there was any way to increase the `get_url` timeout at the playbook level instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set proxy globally via [environment](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html), but not timeout.

As a workaround, you can make custom action plugin to decorate `get_url` calls.
It can overwrite `timeout` parameter with increased value instead of default `10`.

I've posted example of this technique for `setup` module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182680/2795592).

Comment: For now I went with a wrapper role that plays the get_url task before the third-party role gets called. But your solution looks way cleaner as it can be used for all instances of get_url and be kept out of source control so it is only used as fix on my environment. I'll give it a try and accept your answer if it works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: WIll it set proxy for all modules like `win_chocolatey`?

Answer (score 0):

`~/.ansible.cfg`

```
[persistent_connection]
command_timeout = 60
```